# Mini Drawer from Material UI Link Menu page displays as new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

am working on a project to update stocks and am using material ui.
i used mini drawer from material ui, when i click menu link it routes to new page instead of rendering in the homepage itself.

App.JS is where i made some routes

```
import MiniDrawer from './HomePage'
import GetData from './GetData'
import Wrapper from './Wrapper'
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
<Router>
<Switch>
<Route path='/' exact component={MiniDrawer}/>
<Route path='/GetData' component={GetData}/>
<Route path='/Wrapper' component={Wrapper}/>
</Switch>
</Router>
{/* <MiniDrawer/> */}
</div>
);
}
export default App;
```

HomePage.js take a look at the Link property, when i click on the link it open new page instead on displaying in homepage
Here is where we are passing the link to make the routes, when i click here it redirects to new page insted of displaying the component in homepage itself
GetData code to fetch details from DB

```
<List>
<ListItem button component={Link} to="/GetData">
<ListItemIcon>
<InboxIcon />
</ListItemIcon>
<ListItemText primary="GetData" />
```

Wrapper Code for product input

```
[![</ListItem>
<ListItem button component={Link} to="/Wrapper">
<ListItemIcon>
<MailIcon />
</ListItemIcon>
<ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
</ListItem>
</List>
<main className={classes.content} style={{height:"100vh"}}>
<div className={classes.toolbar} />
{/* <Wrapper/> */}
</main>
</div>
);
}][1]][1]
```

Any Help will be very much appreciated

SandBox Link https://codesandbox.io/s/great-tdd-or04i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Can you provide source code in sandbox instead for more clarity.

Comment: SandBox Code, I need test content to be displayed in MiniDrawer instead of separate page, is that possible ?  https://codesandbox.io/s/great-tdd-or04i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

For Now, I found the WorkAround, instead of routing all pages to index.js. I just routed the page which needs to be rendered into Main Layout Page

[Here is the sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vidhaath-materialui-2p3jq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)